# Какой максимально высокий уровень для рисования UML-диаграмм?

Tags: uml

До недавнего времени думал, что есть только диаграммы классов. Недавно узнал, что отношения между пакетами тоже задаются UML-диаграммами. А между пакетами, содержащими несколько пакетов? Например, всего есть 30 пакетов, но 5 из них являются пакетами более высокого уровня (каждый содержит в себе по 5 вложенных пакетов). В такой ситуации стоит нарисовать 3 диаграммы? Для 5 пакетов верхнего уровня. потом для 25 вложенных пакетов и потом уже для классов?

Comment: (или же это вообще неважно, [если есть хорошие инструменты](http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/clusteringByZoom.html))

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите. Но как вариант, Enterprise Architect работает с пакетами. Вот несколько ссылок с инфой:

1. [Харабарх](https://habr.com/company/lanit/blog/352826/)
2. [Документация](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/automation/package_2.html)